# Properly format currency using CurrencyFormatter on UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, localization, format, currency-formatting

I would like to format a price based on it's currency using the [CurrencyFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.numberformatting.currencyformatter) but the resulting strings are unexpected. In the following example, I would expect the resulting string to be `₩123,456`:

```
var currencyFormat = new CurrencyFormatter("KRW"); //, new[] { "ko-KR" }, "KR");
var formatted = currencyFormat.Format(123456); // ₩123456
```

Using the "old-fashioned" way, the expected result is being returned:

```
var formatted = 123456.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("ko-KR")); // ₩123,456
```

So the question is: Is there a reason for the `CurrencyFormatter` to ommit the grouping characters and is there a away around this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `IsGrouped` property for setting whether the integer part of the currency value should be grouped. Try this, It helps you;

```
currencyFormat.IsGrouped = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could set this property for KRW, but the idea is to properly format a price by only knowing the currency ISO symbol. If I know all the configuration data per currency, I could actually write my own `CurrencyFormatter` instead.

Comment: I just tried for your given example and it worked. You are welcome, good look to you ;)